# ZXing Library - Output Result

Tags: android, zxing, mobile-application

I am building an Inventory Management Android App.

I am using **ZXing barcode library** however, I am not sure how to output results.

The idea of scanning is to scan a retail product's barcode and the scanner should output results for the following fields:

`Product Name:`
`Price:`
`Bar code number:`

I am not sure how to overcome this challenge.

Any advice will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use barcode number, product name and price in a single new barcode code. For example, generate common barcode with "productName-price-barcodeNumbe"like this type of order, and when you get these barcode from OnActivtyResponse in acivity by using Zxing library, then you can break this barcode string in same order.